# Typescript: fill table filter values from query string (best approach for async calls)

Tags: angular, typescript

I use typescript (for angular).
I have table with filters (drop downs). Data for each filter are requested from backend and all calls are async. So first I need to load data for all filters. At the same time I need to set default values for filters taking these values from query string. Thus I have to subscribe to `route.queryParams`.

I am not able to do this in right way, because of asynchronous calls, subscription and similar. Unfourtunately I am not so familiar with Typescript yet.

Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._service.getTypes() // get types - data for filter1
        .subscribe((result) => {
            this.types = result.items;

            this._route // subscribe to queryparams and set selected value for filter1
                .queryParams
                .subscribe(params => {
                    if (params['Type'] != undefined) {
                        this.selectedId = parseInt(params['LoadType']);
                    }
                });
        });

    this._service.getClients() // get data for filter2
        .subscribe((result) => {
            this.clients = result.items; 
            this._route // set default value from query str for filter2
                .queryParams
                .subscribe(params => {
                    if (params['ClientCode'] != undefined) {
                        this.client = params['ClientCode'];                            
                    }
                });
        });

       ...
```

And so on for multiple filter, multiple times I subscribe to queryParams. I believe it is wrong.

Comment: Interesting question, do not know of how you would do that.  

All I can think is maybe using Observable.forkJoin 
```Observable.forkJoin(
  this._service.getClients().map(res=>{this.types = result.items;})
 this._service.getTypes().map(res=>{this.types = result.items;}) 
)
.subscribe( res =>  {...Set defaults together...});```

Comment: Maybe if you add the tag rxjs you might some better answers.

Answer (score 0):

As `route.queryParams` subscription does not depend on `getTypes()` and `getClients()` subscriptions result, you may write them separately, subscribing to `route.queryParams` only once:

```
  // subscribe to queryparams and set selected value for filter1 and filter2
  this._route
  .queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
      if (params['Type'] != undefined) {
          this.selectedId = parseInt(params['LoadType']);
      }
      if (params['ClientCode'] != undefined) {
        this.client = params['ClientCode'];                            
      }
  });

  this._service.getTypes() // get types - data for filter1
      .subscribe((result) => {
          this.types = result.items;
      });

  this._service.getClients() // get data for filter2
      .subscribe((result) => {
          this.clients = result.items; 
      });
```